# Can the same query be done with Pivot?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as

```
CREATE TABLE #FinalRates
(
id int primary key identity(1,1),
RateDesc nvarchar(50),
Amt decimal(18,2)
)

insert into #FinalRates values('100',200)
insert into #FinalRates values('100',300)
insert into #FinalRates values('50-80',100)
insert into #FinalRates values('50-80',300)
insert into #FinalRates values('30-50',500)
insert into #FinalRates values('30-50',250)
```

Looking for an output as

```
RateDesc    Amount1 Amount2
100          200    300
50-80        100    300
30-50        500    250
```

I have done this as

```
;with cte as(
select 
                RateDesc 
                ,Amounts=
                      STUFF((Select ','+ cast(cast(Amt as int) as varchar(10))
                      from #FinalRates T1
                       where T1.RateDesc=T2.RateDesc
                       FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 
from #FinalRates T2
group by T2.RateDesc
)

select 
        RateDesc,
        Amount1 = PARSENAME(REPLACE(Amounts,',','.'),2),
        Amount2 = PARSENAME(REPLACE(Amounts,',','.'),1)
From Cte

Drop table #FinalRates
```

Can the same be done using PIVOT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's so complicated.  How about this?

```
select ratedesc,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then amt end) as Amount1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then amt end) as Amount2
from (select ft.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ratedesc order by id) as seqnum
      from #finalrates fr
     ) fr
group by ratedesc;
```

You could use a similar approach using `pivot` but conditional aggregation often performs better.

Plus, if you know you have no holes in `id`, you can do:

```
select ratedesc,
       max(case when id % 2 = 1 then amt end) as Amount1,
       max(case when id % 2 = 0 then amt end) as Amount2
from #finalrates fr
group by ratedesc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using PIVOT,

Assuming you have 2 Amt for each RateDesc.

```
Select RateDesc, [Amount1], [Amount2] From
(
    Select RateDesc, Amt
    , 'Amount' + cast(row_number() over (partition by RateDesc order by Amt) as varchar(5)) RowVal
    from #FinalRates
) x
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Amt) For RowVal in ([Amount1], [Amount2])
) p
```